# Array is not give proper output for foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am not sure what do these Issues mean, so any suggestion will be appreciated.

```php
foreach ($workerdata as $key => $value) {
    $eductions = WorkerCategories::select('Worker_type')->where('Workertype_id','=',$value)->first();
        
    $worker =  $eductions->Worker_type;
    $demo = array($worker);
    print_r($demo);
    $users['worker_category'] = $demo;
}      

exit();
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apartment Prepping
)
Array
(
    [0] => Carpenter
)
```

I want:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apartment Prepping
)
Array
(
    [1] => Carpenter
)
```

Thank you for this.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `$users['worker_category'][] = $worker;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

everytime you call `array($worker)`, this creates a new array that has nothing to do with previous, this why the index remains `0`:

```php
foreach ($workerdata as $key => $value) {
    $eductions = WorkerCategories::select('Worker_type')->where('Workertype_id','=',$value)->first();

    $users['worker_category'][] = $eductions->Worker_type; //push to array worker type.
}      

exit();

print_r($users['worker_category']);

Array
(
    [0] => Apartment Prepping
    [1] => Carpenter
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside in your foreach loop array($worker); creates a new array per iteration, as a result you get [0] indexd array.
For solve this you have to set the index value manually. See Bellow code.

```
$index=0;
foreach ($workerdata as $key => $value) {
    $eductions = WorkerCategories::select('Worker_type')->where('Workertype_id','=',$value)->first();
        
    $worker =  $eductions->Worker_type;
    $demo = array($index++ => $worker);
    print_r($demo);
    $users['worker_category'] = $demo;
}      

exit();
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apartment Prepping
)
Array
(
    [1] => Carpenter
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we should do here is

```
$workerdata = array_values($workerdata);
```

In this way, we don't need to hit the database so many times. Just one query with all the worker ids we have

```
$eductions = WorkerCategories::select(['Worker_type'])->whereIn('Workertype_id',$workerdata)->get();
```

Define an empty array to store your values

```
$user = [];
```

then loop through your results

```
foreach($eductions as $eduction){
     $user[] = $education->worker_category;
}
print_r($user);
```